Символы вместо слов при запуске кода
Запускаю код в VS Code, выдаёт какие-то символы вместо слов и написать ничего нельзя в терминале.


Ответ где-то здесь

Отключите или удалите расширение Code Runner. Cтандартное расширение Python и так умеет запускать код, и у него нет кучи проблем, которые добавляет Code Runner.
